# Cannot create new client ID (for google plus signin in iOS sdk)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, google-plus

I am not able to create oAuth client ID for my iOS app.My app is not create in Apple iTunes App Store because i cannot enter AppStore ID. Here i am attaching two screen shots.First one is create client id form and second one is my error screen shot.How to solve this issue?Please help me..

[image]

I am getting error like this....
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This a new issue with new google console and happening for around last 10 days for iOS. To solve this for now, go to old console and try with same way you did earlier.
This is the URL for old console(carefully look ?noredirect, this is needed.)
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect