# An issue with creating OAuth 2.0 Client ID for iOS Application in Google Developer Console

Tags: ios, oauth, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to create new OAuth 2.0 Client ID for iOS Application in Google Developer Console and got the following error:

> Server Error
>
> Whoops! Our bad.
>
> Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using
>   the "Send feedback" link below. Copy the tracking number below, and
>   include it with your feedback. Thanks!
>
> Tracking Number: undefined

Here are the steps on how I create the Client ID:

1. Open Google Developer Console
2. Pick an existing project with Google+ API added (if it doesn't exist - create one and add Google+ API)
3. Choose "APIs & auth" section and pick "Credentials" field
4. Click on "Create new Client ID"
5. Choose Application Type "Installed Application"
6. Choose Installed Application Type "iOS"
7. Enter valid "Bundle ID" and leave "App Store ID" field blank.
8. Disable "Deep Linking"
9. Click "Create new Client ID"
10. An error dialogue is raised.

Does anybody have any thoughts on that?
Thank you.

Comment: Closed because of answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907841/cannot-create-new-client-id-for-google-plus-signin-in-ios-sdk